# Screen Comments with globes like the Iphone

Tags: android, android-widget

What's the best way to create a screen with comments surrounded by a globe image? I have to create [this](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ojVHzJxnrrXWKM:http://www.realvail.com/images/tomblog/iphone_text_message.jpg&t=1).

Answer (score 0):

Just put your text in a TextView with the background set to a [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) configured to look like a speech bubble. ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o5Io.png))